# Put image and content into jQuery dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dialog

I want to make a dialog box where the user can see the image that he/she has just uploaded. The file uploading systems works fine but when I want to put the image into the dialog box dynamically only an empty box appears.
**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="dialogbox">{I want to change this conetent here to an image}</div>
```

**jQuery/Javascript Code:**

```
function completeHandler(event){
    var data = event.target.responseText;
    var datArray = data.split("|");
    if(datArray[0] == "upload_complete_msg"){
        hasImage = datArray[1];
        $(function() {
            $("#dialogbox").dialog();
            $("#dialogbox").html('sadasdasd');
        });
    } else {
        _("uploadDisplay_SP_msg_"+datArray[2]).innerHTML = datArray[0];
        _("triggerBtn_SP_"+datArray[2]).style.display = "block";
    }
```

The `datArray[]` is a response text from the PHP validation. `datArray[0]` is equal to `upload_complete_msg` if it succeeded, `datArray[1]` is the image file name and extension like `filename123.jpg` and `darArray[2]` is just an id. So as I said if the user has successfully uploaded the image a dialog box should appear. I tried to add more content with the `.html()` function but it didn't show me anything again just an empty dialog box. How would it be possible to put an image into this dialog box like `$("#dialogbox").html('<img src="imgfolder/myimage.jpg">');`?

Comment: debug, debug, debug. I would start by `console.log(data)` right off, see exactly what you're getting back.

Comment: As I said I don't have any problems with the file uploading only with the displaying. But here is the data: `upload_complete_msg|filemg1513187555.jpg|47`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```js
function completeHandler(event) {
  var data = event.target.responseText;
  var datArray = data.split("|");
  if (datArray[0] == "upload_complete_msg") {
    hasImage = "tempUploads/"+datArray[1];
    // Create a jQuery image object, and assign the src attribute.
    var imgEl = $("<img>").attr("src", hasImage);
    // stick that imgEl into the dialog.
    $("#dialogbox").html(imgEl);
    $("#dialogbox").dialog();

  } else {
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_msg_" + datArray[2]).innerHTML = datArray[0];
    _("triggerBtn_SP_" + datArray[2]).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be better but I do not have the image as a url. I have it in a folder called `tempUploads`. So the image what is the code is searching for is something like this: `http://localhost/social_media/root/filename1513188174.jpg`

Comment: But I located my image like this: `tempUploads/filename1513188174.jpg`

Comment: Did that get you there? Appreciate the upvote, always curious about "what happens after"...